# Fatal error after subtheming Commerce Kickstart Admin Theme

Tags: commerce, theming

I am trying to subtheme Commerce Kickstart Admin Theme. I have copied all the folders and files to sites/all/themes/my__admin_subtheme, and changed the appropriate lines in my_admin_subtheme.info.

When I go to /admin/appearance, and change the section Administration theme to My Admin Theme, I get an error in template.php telling that the function commerce_kickstart_admin_preprocess_maintenance_page is declared twice.

How to solve this issue?

Edit:

When I change the name of preprocess function in template.php from commerce_kickstart_admin_preprocess_maintenance_page to my_admin_subtheme_preprocess_maintenance_page or delete template.php the fatal error disappear but I lose the formated html present in that function.

To make things more clear, the template.php is

```
<?php

/**
 * Override or insert variables into the maintenance page template.
 */
function livraria_acervo_admin_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$vars) {
  // While markup for normal pages is split into page.tpl.php and html.tpl.php,
  // the markup for the maintenance page is all in the single
  // maintenance-page.tpl.php template. So, to have what's done in
  // shiny_preprocess_html() also happen on the maintenance page, it has to be
  // called here.
  shiny_preprocess_html($vars);
  if (variable_get('install_task') != 'done') {
    $footer_markup =  '<div class="message">' . t('Proudly built by') . '</div>';
    $footer_markup .=  '<div class="logo">' . t('<a href="@url">Commerce Guys</a>', array('@url' => 'http://www.commerceguys.com')) . '</div>';
    $vars['footer'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div id="credit" class="clearfix">',
      '#markup' => $footer_markup,
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
  }
}
```

I searched for that function in all file tree in root Drupal installation and didn't find any call for that function.

I see the function is related to the maintenance mode, the mode that I'm working now. Well, as I told above the fatal error disappeared but how to know where the function is called. I think the function is called somewhere and I would have to change the name in the file(s) that it's called, although I don't think this would the better way to solve the problem.

So some piece is missing in subtheming Commerce Kickstart 2 admin theme, and is related to the call of that function commerce_kickstart_admin_preprocess_maintenance_page.

I'm new to Drupal and have not practiced php very much, so I hope I have been cleared. If more information is needed please tell me. And sorry about my English too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

PHP requires all function names to be unique*, you'll need to rename the functions in your sub-theme to `my_admin_subtheme_FUNCTION_NAME`, e.g. `my_admin_subtheme__preprocess_page(&$vars)`.

You might want to consider clearing the `template.php` file completely and only copying the functions you need when you find you need them.

- That is unique in a namespace, but that is another subject - see http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply @bloke_zero, I have tried your suggestion. The fatal error has gone, but the rendered html that is made by that preprocess function with the changed name to my_subtheme_FUNCTION_NAME doesn't work. I edited the question with the function and more information for a better analyses. Thanks again.

Comment: There are 2 things I can think of, 1. Are you setting the base theme (https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) - you need something like `base theme = theme_name` in your `.info` file.

2. Have you cleared the cache?  As the preprocess functions won't show up until you do.